# How to change properties of chart legend

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts, properties, legend

I'm having difficulties with tuning the layout of the legend of my C# chart in VS2017. When I go to `Legends` in `Properties` I can change several properties but I can't find how to change the margin between the border of the legend and its items (so, the **padding** actually). Another property I don't manage to change: **spacing** between the legend items. I found some discussions concerning "style files", but I would like to avoid that. I also searched for different references that could give me more options, but I didn't find anything.

So, is there a way to change the properties of a legend, other than the ones that are displayed in `Properties`? I hope to find something like: "myLegend.padding = 10pt".

Comment: Is this a WPF project, or WinForms? ASP.net?  What charting package are you using?

Comment: It's a WinForms app, using .NET Framework 4. At the moment I don't use any specific charting package cause the only one that I find is `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization(.Charting)` and that's not doing anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`CustomizeLegend`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.customizelegend(v=vs.110).aspx) event of the chart to style the `Legend`, its `LegendItems` and their `LegendCells`.

The [Margin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.legendcell.margins(v=vs.110).aspx) you are looking for is a property of the [`LegendCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.legendcell(v=vs.110).aspx)

> A Margins object that represents the top, bottom, left, and right
>   values of the legend cell margins. The default values for top, bottom,
>   left and right are "0,0,15,15".
>
> Margins are measured as a **percentage of the font size** for the legend
>   cell

This means that for a normal `LegendItem`, which consists of **two** `Cells`, one for the series **marker** and one for the **text**, you need to set two margins.

Here is an example; it creates a 30% top margin, no bottom margins, also for the 1st, the left marker cell a 400% (left) margin, for the 2nd (right) text cell a 200% right margin. A padding between the cells is added to the text cell and is 100%..:

```
private void chart1_CustomizeLegend(object sender, CustomizeLegendEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (LegendItem lit in e.LegendItems)
    {
        var cells = lit.Cells;
        cells[0].Margins = new Margins(30, 0, 400, 100);
        cells[1].Margins = new Margins(30, 0, 0, 200);
    }
}
```

Let's see it in action; I have added two colors to the cells so you can see the respective areas better:

[image]

Here is the updated, dynamic code:

```
cells[0].Margins = new Margins(tr_top.Value, tr_bot.Value, tr_ll.Value, tr_mm.Value);
cells[1].Margins = new Margins(tr_top.Value, tr_bot.Value, tr_mm.Value, tr_rr.Value);
```

Comment: How do I call this event? I tried it like this: `chart1.CustomizeLegend += new System.xxx.Charting.CustomizeLegendEventArgs(chart1_CustomizedLegend)` and `void chart_CustomizedLegend(object sender, CustomizeLegendEventArgs e)` but then I get the message: _cannot convert from MethodGroup to LegendItemsCollection_.

Comment: You hook it up as always, best by doubleclicking it in the events pane! And you don't call it but trigger it by calling Invalidate(). Unless you do dynamic stuff like my last example you don't need to call it at all, as it will be called automatically whenever the Legend gets drawn..